# Run single python method many times simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, post, multiprocessing

I have a method which takes one argument, and post to a host.

```
def fts(searchstring):
    search_string="\""+searchstring+"\""
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
    data = '{ "explain": true,"fields": ["*"],"highlight": {},"query": { "query": '+search_string+'},"size":0}'
    response = requests.post('hostname', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('uname', 'password'))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("{} - {}".format(response.status_code, response.text))
    print(response.json())
```

I want to run this method in several processes at a time with different arguments. Is this possible? I tried to use multiprocessing but couldn't able to get it.
Thanks

Comment: show code with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: BTW: there are modules which use `requests+threading`, `requests+multiprocessing`, `requests+asyncio`

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool
agents = 30
with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
        result = pool.map(fts,searchstring)`

Is this executing simultaneously?

Comment: pardon for poor indentation

Comment: code `pool.map(fts,searchstring)` will run simultaneously but it will treat `searchstring` as  list of chars and send every single char to different `fts` - you need `all_results = pool.map(fts, [searchstring1, searchstring2, searchstring3, ...])`

Comment: Thanks, this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code `pool.map(fts, searchstring)` will run simultaneously but it will treat `searchstring` as list of chars and send every single char to different `fts`

You need list with all strings

```
all_results = pool.map(fts, [searchstring1, searchstring2, searchstring3, ...])
```

---

**BTW:** If you will need to send more arguments then you will need list with tuples or sublists.

```
all_results = pool.map(fts, [(searchstring1, param1), (searchstring2, param2), ...])
```

and define function as

```
def fts(args):
    searchstring, param = args
```